# Nesting multiple DATEDIFs in IF function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Does anyone know how to nest multiple DATEDIFs in an IF function? I was able to get the result I wanted to achieve with one one date condition and return the value if it matched but I'm not able to enter multiple date ranges, as well as return values if they matched.

Here's what I could get to work:`IF(DATEDIF(DATE-1,DATE-2,"COUNTS DAYS BETWEEN DATES SELECTED")="DAYS IN A WEEK","VALUE IF TRUE","VALUE IF NOT TRUE")`

But I'm trying to return values for a users selected date ranges (1 day = value 1, 1 week = value 2, 1 month = value 3). If anyone has a suggestion, please pass it along! :)

Comment: How does 1 day, 1 week and 1 month relate to the dates? Can you provide sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: `=CHOOSE(MATCH(ABS(A1-B1),{0,7,30},1),"Value1","Value2","Value3")` where `A1` and `B1` contain the two dates *could* do what you want.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad this worked great, thanks! Is there any way to nest a "no goal found" if the days in the formula {0,7,30) are not selected from the two dates (A1-B1)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that question. [the MATCH documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A) may be of help